# Actionscript: Sorting ArrayCollection by date: YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sorting, date, arraycollection

I have an ArrayCollection of Objects. Each Object has the following keys/values:

```
{date: 2009-12-01, visits=13555, bouceRate=45}
{date: 2009-12-05, visits=46955, bouceRate=45}
{date: 2009-12-06, visits=13685, bouceRate=45}
{date: 2009-12-02, visits=13685, bouceRate=45}
{date: 2009-12-04, visits=68755, bouceRate=45}
{date: 2009-12-03, visits=35875, bouceRate=45}
```

I need to sort this ArrayCollection by date, so it would be from past to present - like so:

```
{date: 2009-12-01, visits=13555, bouceRate=45}
{date: 2009-12-02, visits=13685, bouceRate=45}
{date: 2009-12-03, visits=35875, bouceRate=45}
{date: 2009-12-04, visits=68755, bouceRate=45}
{date: 2009-12-05, visits=46955, bouceRate=45}
{date: 2009-12-06, visits=13685, bouceRate=45}
```

---

I have tried the following with no prevail (not sorting):

```
var dateSort:Sort = new Sort();
    dateSort.fields = [new SortField("date", false, false, true)];

newAreaChartData.sort = dateSort;
newAreaChartData.refresh();

// traceout
for (var i:int = 0; i <newAreaChartData.length; i++)
    trace ("Object #" + i + ": " + ObjectUtil.toString(newAreaChartData.getItemAt(i)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
for(i = 0; i < newAreaChartData.length; ++i) {
    newAreaChartData[i].formattedDate = getActualDate(newAreaChartData[i].date);
    newAreaChartData[i].dateTime =    newAreaChartData[i].formattedDate.time;
    trace(newAreaChartData[i].dateTime);
}

    var dateSort:Sort = new Sort();
    dateSort.fields = [new SortField("dateTime", false, false, true)];
    newAreaChartData.sort = dateSort; 
    newAreaChartData.refresh();

for (var i:int = 0; i <newAreaChartData.length; i++)
    trace ("Object #"+ i + ": " + ObjectUtil.toString(newAreaChartData.getItemAt(i)));
```

Comment: Yeah, as I mentionned, this works because you convert the date to a number of milliseconds since epoch. This is okay, but since you're using the US format, the date can be sorted using lexical ordering.

Answer (score 1):

The way your creating the SortField :

```
new SortField("date", false, false, true)
```

From the [API](http://www.igorcosta.com/flex3/doc/mx/collections/SortField.html#SortField%28%29) , the last parameter should mean that you want the value to be sorted numerically instead of as a string.

What is the type of the "date" field in the Object ? If it is a string, then you might want to sort things alphabetically

```
new SortField("date", false, false, null)
```

Hoping this helps

PH

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the sort is applied until you call ArrayCollection.refresh():

```
newAreaChartData.sort = dateSort;
newAreaChartData.refresh();
```

Comment: true, but the above (edited) still does not sort it by date.
Thanks Erich