# How can i sort months using SortField in Flex3?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, actionscript-3

I am sorting xmllist profilexml. In the list dates and months are sorted using `SortField`. It is sorting up to September month. After that Oct, Nov, and Dec are coming and displaying on the top in the datagrid.

```
finalList = new XMLListCollection(profileXml);
var sortL:Sort = new Sort();
sortL.fields = [new SortField("startDate", true)];
finalList.sort = sortL;
finalList.refresh();
popupProfile.dataGrid.dataProvider = finalList;
```

My XmlList is in this format: `<startDate>1/11/2011</startDate>`.

`<startDate>2/15/2011</startDate>` as per my understanding it is sorting until 0-9 numeric fields only. Is there anything I need to add in this code for numeric sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a couple of things:

- Set the numeric property of your `[SortField][1]` to true.

`sortL.fields= [new SortField("startDate", true, false, true)];`

- Convert your date from a string into an actual Date object before performing the sort.
- If you're sorting in a `DataGrid`, you can use your own `sortCompareFunction`. [FlexExamples has an example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/12/sorting-date-columns-in-a-datagrid/) for this one.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868197/actionscript-sorting-arraycollection-by-date-yyyy-mm-dd) might also help.